# How create a Java list based in a JavaScript array?

Tags: java, javascript, json, gson

I don't know much about JavaScript, but I was able to convert an array of double (in Java) to an array in JavaScript too, using json (with Gson).

But now I need to convert this list below in some list of objects, so it can be dynamic on my server side to send to the client side.

```
plotBands: [{ // Light air
                from: 0.3,
                to: 1.5,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Light air',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Light breeze
                from: 1.5,
                to: 3.3,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Light breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Gentle breeze
                from: 3.3,
                to: 5.5,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Gentle breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Moderate breeze
                from: 5.5,
                to: 8,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Moderate breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Fresh breeze
                from: 8,
                to: 11,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Fresh breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Strong breeze
                from: 11,
                to: 14,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Strong breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // High wind
                from: 14,
                to: 15,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'High wind',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }]
```

How should be this class in Java ? So I can use Json (with Gson) to parse it.

I think should be something like:

```
class Info 
    private float from;
    private float to;
    private String color;
    private Label label;

class Label
   private String text;
   private Style style;

class Style
   private String color;
```

And in the end I have a `List<Info> plotBands`   and use `.toJson` method.
Am I thinking right ? Or there's something I'm missing here ?

**UPDATE**
In my .xhtml page I have :

```
<h:outputScript>var data = ${reportc.dataAsJson};</h:outputScript>
```

I create these class above that I mentioned:
Then I create :

```
List<Info> infos = new ArrayList<Info>();
infos.add(new Info(0, 10, "rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)", new Label("Cold", new Style("#606060"))));
data.put("plotBands", infos);
```

This generate the follow javascript code:

```
{"plotBands":[{
    "from":0.0,
    "to":10.0,
    "color":"rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)",
    "label":{
        "text":"Cold",
        "style":{
             "color":"#606060"
         }
    }
}]
```

Which it seems correct, but how to pass this to my [javascript code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5714646/example.js) ?
I'm trying but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What happens when you run Gson? Does it give the expected JSON string back?

Comment: I want to create a dynamic 'plotBands' in Java so I can use Json to parse it, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I understand that you are having problems with it, but I do not see/understand the concrete problem. At what step exactly are you failing?

Comment: @BalusC I update my post, please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your JS file, replace

```
plotBands: [{ // Light air
                from: 0.3,
                to: 1.5,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Light air',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Light breeze
                from: 1.5,
                to: 3.3,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Light breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Gentle breeze
                from: 3.3,
                to: 5.5,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Gentle breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Moderate breeze
                from: 5.5,
                to: 8,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Moderate breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Fresh breeze
                from: 8,
                to: 11,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Fresh breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // Strong breeze
                from: 11,
                to: 14,
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                label: {
                    text: 'Strong breeze',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }, { // High wind
                from: 14,
                to: 15,
                color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.1)',
                label: {
                    text: 'High wind',
                    style: {
                        color: '#606060'
                    }
                }
            }]
```

by

```
plotBands: data.plotBands
```

Comment: Thank you, I was having problems with 'plotBands' in the server side and with 'plotbands' in the client side.
But now everything works fine.
Thank you Bauke.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Style
   private String color;
```